# Why is uEFI firmware unable to access a software RAID 1 /boot/efi partition?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, uefi, mdadm, gpt

BIOS firmware can boot a BIOS formatted /boot partition installed on a software RAID 1 pair no problem. It can even boot from a /boot installed on LVM volume that lives on a software RAID 1 pair.

But with a uEFI install, /boot/efi has to be on a non md partition or the firmware can not access it.

Is this a flaw with uEFI firmware? Or is the problem with how Ubuntu sets up /boot/efi on software RAID devices? Could it be a flaw with how GPT partition tables present software RAID to the firmware?

For reference, I’m using:
Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 64bit
mdadm RAID setup from the 'Manual' option in the partitioner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EFI knows how to access FAT and FAT32 filesystems.  This is why your EFI boot partition has to be FAT or FAT32 formatted.  EFI however does **not** know how to read a software RAID 1 partition, even if it is formatted using FAT32.  There is a pretty simple away around this, at least using Arch Linux.  When installing the system, you set the boot partition up as a FAT32 formatted raid, but you direct EFI to boot off of the individual partitions.  Specifically, you do this.

```
 mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata 1.0 --raid-devices=2 --level=1 /dev/sd[ab]1
 mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/md0
```

Then proceed with the installation.  As far as EFI is concerned, though, the boot partitions are /dev/sda1 and /dev/sb1 *individually*.  You set each one up as a boot device, and then if, say, /dev/sda fails, the system will still boot from /dev/sdb1.  After the system is booted the /dev/md0 RAID 1 kicks in, insuring that /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 stay synchronized.

I set all my systems up like this and haven't had any problems.  (Note that setting the mdadm metadata to 1.0 is necessary when installing a software raid on a boot partition.)

Comment: Clearly, you are correct that EFI cannot read software RAID 1 partition. Ultimately, the solution for me is not installing boot/root filesystems on disk drives larger than 2GB. This avoids the dilemma where disks 2GB+ require a GPT partition table and therefore ordinary BIOS cannot boot from. I’m not sure that the Ubuntu Server installation process would support the instructions you posted.